# Should we delete the "api" tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Should we delete [api](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api)?  It doesn't seem to add value, and on stackoverflow the guidance is "DO NOT USE: Tag with the library you mean, [api-design], or something else appropriate instead."

Comment: Before we delete it we should compile a list of possible replacements, e.g., json-api, ... How would you tag a question about an API of a block explorer for instance?

Comment: The tag of the block explorer is enough imo.  Examples: tag with blockexplorer and transactions, blockexplorer and raw-transaction, blockexplorer and events...  Tag with what api is being looked for (like events), and if known, what the service is (like blockexplorer)

Comment: Go ahead and remove it. While it's only used on 26 question and it's not high-priority in my eyes, I don't see any reason why we should keep it. Do you have any idea for link, synonym or replacement, yet?

Comment: I think it is a fuzzy tag, we should adopt more specific tags .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at the api tag today, in a hope of CULLING THE HERD, but I had trouble finding targets!

There's several which are reasonable questions about the *existence* of a given API. For example, [a python API](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3710/reading-deployed-contract-state-in-python), or a [webhook API](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2373/ethereum-blockchain-webhook-api), etc. I'm not sure what a new user is supposed to label their question if not "API".

Perhaps *that* could be the use of the API tag? Or create some tag which would suffice?

EDIT:

After some thought, I think api-design might be a worthy replacement, since I could see a legitimate set of questions on the subject. api is otherwise a bad tag, and even the potential set of questions I mentioned previously are not really stack overflow style questions. But *designing* an api, I think, is a worthy enough question, and I believe I saw one or two like that.

EDIT 2:

I brought [api](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) use down to about 15 questions. I see there's a tag called [external-api](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-api), which I feel is worth keeping. Or, at least, keeping it with the meaning of "Interacting outside of Ethereum with things such as Oraclize.it" Perhaps not?

EDIT 3:

It's done. No questions were lost, and there weren't any that were too hard to decide how to retag.

EDIT 4:

Apologies if I did it a little too fast. I realize I now occupy almost the entire front page. (Is this normal during tagicide?)

Comment: If you already went through some of the tagged questions, you could also suggest replacement tags.